RAISERROR / THROW and sp_start_job Termination Behaviour
Given the following SQL Server Agent job
USE [msdb]
GO


BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'Do Nothing', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'No description available.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'Me', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Wait', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'WAITFOR DELAY ''00:00:10''', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:
GO

And the following calling code
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'Do nothing' -- waits for 10 seconds
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'Do nothing' -- fails, job still running
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'Do nothing' -- should succeed

I get the following error:
Job 'Do nothing' started successfully. Msg 22022, Level 16, State 1, Line 25 SQLServerAgent Error: Request to run job Do Nothing (from User Me) refused because the job is already running from a request by User Me. Job 'Do nothing' started successfully.

So we can see the second sp_start_job call failed because the job was still running, then SQL Server continued execution
the failure is a Level 16 and when I do the following
PRINT 'hello'
    RAISERROR ('error',16,1)
PRINT 'hello'

I get the same "fail and continue" behaviour
hello
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 50
error
hello

however, if I do the following, which also raises a Level 16 error, the second print is not run
PRINT 'hello'
    ;THROW 51000, 'error', 1;
PRINT 'hello'

hello
Msg 51000, Level 16, State 1, Line 50
error

The docs for THROW state

Any error that occurs in a THROW statement causes the statement batch to be terminated.

The docs for RAISERROR state

The error is returned to the caller if RAISERROR is run:
Outside the scope of any TRY block.
With a severity of 10 or lower in a TRY block.
With a severity of 20 or higher that terminates the database connection.

My questions is, is sp_start_job using RAISERROR rather than throw - I have looked into
the definition and can't see if anywhere

Did you try with SET XACT_ABORT ON; at the top of the script?

@Charlieface the PRINT 'hello'
RAISERROR ('error',16,1)
PRINT 'hello' and the sp_start_job scripts give the same behaviour with XACT_ABORT ON

Yes it does use RAISERROR, at least in the parts of the code I can see. There are also some Extended Procedures used internally, and we don't have the source code for those, but I suspect this will be the case here as well.
You should use BEGIN CATCH to catch such errors, as RAISERROR does not terminate execution even when SET XACT_ABORT is ON.
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'Do nothing'; -- waits for 10 seconds
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'Do nothing'; -- fails, job still running
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'Do nothing'; -- should succeed
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'caught';
END CATCH;


Below is the full definition for sp_start_job, you can see it uses RAISERROR in a number of places. You can get this definition using select definition from msdb.sys.sql_modules where object_id = object_id('msdb..sp_start_job').
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_start_job
  @job_name    sysname          = NULL,
  @job_id      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL,
  @error_flag  INT              = 1,    -- Set to 0 to suppress the error from sp_sqlagent_notify if SQLServerAgent is not running
  @server_name sysname          = NULL, -- The specific target server to start the [multi-server] job on
  @step_name   sysname          = NULL, -- The name of the job step to start execution with [for use with a local job only]
  @output_flag INT              = 1     -- Set to 0 to suppress the success message
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @job_id_as_char VARCHAR(36)
  DECLARE @retval         INT
  DECLARE @step_id        INT
  DECLARE @job_owner_sid  VARBINARY(85)

  SET NOCOUNT ON

  -- Remove any leading/trailing spaces from parameters
  SELECT @job_name    = LTRIM(RTRIM(@job_name))
  SELECT @server_name = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@server_name)))
  SELECT @step_name   = LTRIM(RTRIM(@step_name))

  -- Turn [nullable] empty string parameters into NULLs
  IF (@job_name = N'')    SELECT @job_name = NULL
  IF (@server_name = N'') SELECT @server_name = NULL
  IF (@step_name = N'')   SELECT @step_name = NULL

  EXECUTE @retval = sp_verify_job_identifiers '@job_name',
                                              '@job_id',
                                               @job_name OUTPUT,
                                               @job_id   OUTPUT,
                                               @owner_sid = @job_owner_sid OUTPUT
  IF (@retval <> 0)
    RETURN(1) -- Failure

  -- Check permissions beyond what's checked by the sysjobs_view
  -- SQLAgentReader role can see all jobs but
  -- cannot start/stop jobs they do not own
  IF (@job_owner_sid <> SUSER_SID()                      -- does not own the job
     AND (ISNULL(IS_SRVROLEMEMBER(N'sysadmin'), 0) = 0)     -- is not sysadmin
     AND (ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(N'SQLAgentOperatorRole'), 0) = 0))  -- is not SQLAgentOperatorRole
  BEGIN
   RAISERROR(14393, -1, -1);  
   RETURN(1) -- Failure
  END

  IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobservers
                  WHERE (job_id = @job_id)))
  BEGIN
    SELECT @job_id_as_char = CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), @job_id)
    RAISERROR(14256, -1, -1, @job_name, @job_id_as_char)
    RETURN(1) -- Failure
  END

  IF (EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobservers
              WHERE (job_id = @job_id)
                AND (server_id = 0)))
  BEGIN
    -- The job is local, so start (run) the job locally

    -- Check the step name (if supplied)
    IF (@step_name IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
      SELECT @step_id = step_id
      FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps
      WHERE (step_name = @step_name)
        AND (job_id = @job_id)

      IF (@step_id IS NULL)
      BEGIN
        RAISERROR(14262, -1, -1, '@step_name', @step_name)
        RETURN(1) -- Failure
      END
    END

    EXECUTE @retval = msdb.dbo.sp_sqlagent_notify @op_type     = N'J',
                                                  @job_id      = @job_id,
                                                  @schedule_id = @step_id, -- This is the start step
                                                  @action_type = N'S',
                                                  @error_flag  = @error_flag
    IF ((@retval = 0) AND (@output_flag = 1))
      RAISERROR(14243, 0, 1, @job_name)
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    -- The job is a multi-server job

      -- Only sysadmin can start multi-server job
      IF (ISNULL(IS_SRVROLEMEMBER(N'sysadmin'), 0) <> 1)
      BEGIN
         RAISERROR(14397, -1, -1);
         RETURN(1) -- Failure
      END            

    -- Check target server name (if any)
    IF (@server_name IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
      IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM msdb.dbo.systargetservers
                      WHERE (UPPER(server_name) = @server_name)))
      BEGIN
        RAISERROR(14262, -1, -1, '@server_name', @server_name)
        RETURN(1) -- Failure
      END
    END

    -- Re-post the job if it's an auto-delete job
    IF ((SELECT delete_level
         FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
         WHERE (job_id = @job_id)) <> 0)
      EXECUTE @retval = msdb.dbo.sp_post_msx_operation 'INSERT', 'JOB', @job_id, @server_name

    -- Post start instruction(s)
    EXECUTE @retval = msdb.dbo.sp_post_msx_operation 'START', 'JOB', @job_id, @server_name
  END

  RETURN(@retval) -- 0 means success
END


Thanks, turns out I was getting hung up on the fact that it doesn't use raiserror here : EXECUTE @retval = msdb.dbo.sp_post_msx_operation 'START', 'JOB' .... as I thought that is where it would be failing, whereas I suspect it is actually failing here - msdb.dbo.sp_sqlagent_notify where there is a RAISERROR Thankyou :)

@Charlieface , I just read through the source for both sp_start_job and also sp_sqlagent_notify,
I believe that the check for whether the job is already started is done inside xp_sqlagent_notify, for which we don't have the source code. (I might have missed such a check on any of those T-SQL procedures, of course.) So my take on this is that sp_start_job uses none of those T-SQL commands. Pretty academic, of course, since it is the behaviour and how you handle it that is important. :-)

@TiborKaraszi I think you're right as I can't find the throw of error 22022 in sp_sqlagent_notify

@TiborKaraszi My point was more that it uses RAISERROR more generally, so it's not likely that any internal procedures (which you can usually find in the Resource Database if you know how to look) probably use the same mechanism.

@Charlieface xp_sqlagent_notify is an extended stored procedure. This means that the code which implements it is either in a dll file or inside the database engine exe file. I.e., it is not written in T-SQL, hence it doesn't use RAISERROR or THROW. It is probably written in C++, and uses that language's constructs to throw an exception.

@SE1986 See my above comment. This xp (not  the sp, the sp calls the xp) isn't written in T-SQL. Hence the question about whether it uses RAISERROR or THROW sort of ... disappears. Now it is more a matter of this thread is about the behaviour or if it is about whether it uses THROW os RAISERROR (none of those). :-)

I know it's a native proc, but I'd be surprised if the two mechanisms weren't available separately using different functions. Probably THROW uses normal SEH handling, and RAISERROR uses a function to pass an informational message with severity back to the TSQL side. @SeanGallardy could probably tell us more.
